# JavaScript Array: Gives undefined when checking for largest element

Tags: javascript

Okay, so I cannot see what I'm doing wrong.
My tasks is write a function/s that returns the largest element in a list where I have 5 scenarios. (check jasmine)

I'm doing this in Jasmine, so it throws and expects certain results, like this:

```
describe('List', function() {
  'use strict';

  var list;

  beforeEach(function() {
    list = new List();
  });

  it('should find the largest element', function() {
    var data = [1, 100, 32, 453, 21, 5, 23, 12, 90];
    expect(list.findLargest(data)).toBe(453);
  });

  it('should cover negative values', function() {
    var data = [-1, -123, -2, -6, -10000, -10];
    expect(list.findLargest(data)).toBe(-1);
  });

  it('should cover duplicated values', function() {
    var data = [-1, -123, -1, -6, -10000, -1];
    expect(list.findLargest(data)).toBe(-1);
  });

  it('should cover all duplicated values', function() {
    var data = [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3];
    expect(list.findLargest(data)).toBe(3);
  });

  it('should cover empty list', function() {
    expect(function() {
      list.findLargest([]); 
    }).toThrow('List cannot be empty.');
  });

});
```

Here is what I got:

```
var List = function() {
  'use strict';

  function findLargest(list) {
    var largest = [];

    console.log(list);
    if( list[i] > 0){
      for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (largest < list[i] ) {
            largest = list[i];
        }
    }
    console.log(largest);
    return 453;
    //return largest; //Doesn't work
    }

    else if( list[i] < 0 ){
      console.log("negative");
      for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (largest > list[i] ) {
            largest = list[i];
        }
      }
      console.log(largest);
      return largest;
    }

    // else {
    //    throw("List cannot be empty.");
    // }

  }

  return {
    findLargest: findLargest
  };
};
```

I get undefined when I test this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5mIE.jpg

I cannot see how it goes from elements in array, to undefined.

In theory my first function checks if the array has positive or negative numbers, and then it sees which is the biggest. 
I even tried returning the expected value (453), but it stills throws undefined at me.

The else function is for the final scenario where the array is empty.

Comment: To check whether `a` is bigger than `b`, you use `a > b`. This does not depend on whether `a` (or `b`) are negative or not.

Comment: you use `i` without assigned value in the first check ` if( list[i] > 0){`

Comment: Uh, don't comment `return largest;` out if you don't want to get `undefined`? Same for the `else throw …` statement.

Comment: For the first if-condition you basically are calling: `if ([] > list[i])`. Doesn't make sense for me

Answer (score 0):

You set variable `i` to `0` in `for` loop, which is inside if statement, so `list[i] > 0` check throws error because at that time `i` is `undefined`.

Comment: I see. So how would I check the array elements in the `if` ?

Comment: Outer `if` is pointless. Just use `for` loop and one `if` check inside, something like this:
`var largest = list[0]; for (var i = 1; i < list.length; i++) { if (largest < list[i]) { largest = list[i] } } `

Answer (score 0):

You could use a check for the length of the array and return early if no item is in the array.

For the other check take the first element as temporary largest value and check all other elements from index `1`.

There is no need to distinguish between negative and positive arrays.

```js
function findLargest(list) {
    var largest = list[0],
        i;

    if (!list.length) {
        return; // no items
    }
    
    for (i = 1; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (largest < list[i]) {
            largest = list[i];
        }
    }
    return largest;
}

console.log(findLargest([]));
console.log(findLargest([-1, -2, -4, -1]));
console.log(findLargest([2, 5, 3, 7, 2]));
console.log(findLargest([-8, 2, 5, 3, 7, 2]));
```

Answer (score 0):

With [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), the function can be written as:

```js
Array.prototype.findLargest = function() {
  if (this.length === 0) {
    throw("List cannot be empty.")
  }
  return this.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a > b ? a : b
  })
}
var data = [-1, -123, -1, -6, -10000, -1]
var largest = data.findLargest()
console.log(largest)

var data = []
try {
  var largest = data.findLargest()
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e)
}
```

Or simpler ...

```js
var data = [-1, -123, -1, -6, -10000, -1]
var largest = data.reduce(function(a, b) {return a > b ? a : b})
console.log(largest)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing some requirement, you could also make use of `Math.max`:

```js
function findLargest(list) {
  if(list.length)
    return Math.max(...list);
  throw("List cannot be empty.");
}

//test code:
for(let data of [
 [1, 100, 32, 453, 21, 5, 23, 12, 90],
  [-1, -123, -2, -6, -10000, -10],
  [-1, -123, -1, -6, -10000, -1],
  []
])
 console.log('largest in ', JSON.stringify(data), ':', findLargest(data));
```